# Flash Builder MXML component protected variables of extended class not visible in autocomplete

Tags: flash, autocomplete, components, mxml, builder

This has been annoying me for years, sometimes when extending a class as an MXML component in Flash Builder, protected variables of the extended class aren't visible in auto complete. Does anyone know how to fix this?